# Add-in for vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

Is there any add-in for vs 2010 which can format html? ReSharper can't do it.

For example. I wanna get something like this

```
<tr>
 <td>Header1</td>
 <td>Header2</td>
</tr>
```

instread of

```
   <tr>
        <td>Header1</td>
  <td>Header2</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Format Document - works for almost any document type).

Comment: It works, but I need to specify format options. That's why I need add-in.

Comment: You can setup the formatting quite in detail in the options (Text Editor, HTML, Formatting, Tag Specific Options...).